# GitlabCI artifacts not found

Tags: bash, go, gitlab-ci

I'm writing a pipeline for a golang monorepo, and in the unit test job I'm following the docs in order to export the results as xml to be picked up by the UI:

```yaml
unit-test:
  image: golang:1.14
  stage: test
  extends: .go-cache
  before_script:
    - go get -u github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report
  script:
    - $WORKDIR/scripts/test.sh users projects organizations
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: [$WORKDIR/reports/report_users.xml, $WORKDIR/reports/report_projects.xml, $WORKDIR/organizations/report_organizations.xml]
```

where

```sh
$WORKDIR
```

is equivalent to

```sh
$GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME
```

and test.sh script contains the following

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fmt_vet_test() {
  P=$(pwd)
  cd "$P"/"$1" || return

  go fmt ./...
  go vet ./...

  if [[ ! -d "$P"/reports ]]; then
    mkdir "$P"/reports
  fi

  go test -race ./... -v 2>&1 | go-junit-report >"$P"/reports/report_"$1".xml
  cd "$P" || return
}

for SRV in "$@"; do
  fmt_vet_test "$SRV"
done
```

and while running the script locally with the same parameters outputs the reports nicely inside a /reports directory at the root of the repo, the pipeline outputs

```sh
WARNING: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.go/src/gitlab.com/qubuilder/qubuilder-services/reports/report_users.xml: no matching files 
WARNING: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.go/src/gitlab.com/qubuilder/qubuilder-services/reports/report_projects.xml: no matching files 
WARNING: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.go/src/gitlab.com/qubuilder/qubuilder-services/organizations/report_organizations.xml: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up file based variables 00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

and it's beyond my grasp why.

Comment: Your test.sh assumes that CWD it's run from is the project dir, but that doesn't appear to be the case when it's being run in GitLab.

Comment: And how could I change that issue?

Comment: Fix your script.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? `P=$WORKDIR` should work in your script.

Comment: still not, and my boss moved the whole team to a different project so I don't think I will handle this in the near future